# In sql, what is the most efficient way to find nearest pairs of points for two tables

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, geospatial

let's say i have `tableA.points` which has a bunch of geographic points.

and i have `tableB.points` which has a bunch of geographic points, as well.

i want to compare every row in `tableA.points` to every row in `tableB.points`, and list the closest (shortest distance) point for each row in `tableA.points`.

so, actually two points:

1. the only way i can think of is a cartesian product (cross join) or a aggregate correlated subquery.
2. the issue with the correlated subquery is that i can't attach `tableB.Identifer` to the outer query.

for example:

```
SELECT
  tableA.*
  ,(SELECT
      CONCAT(tableB.IDENTIFIER,':',MIN(ST_DISTANCE(tableA.points, tableB.points))
    FROM tableB) as closest_point
FROM tableA
```

The big problem here is that i have over a million rows for each of these tables...

Any advice?

edit: i could also use zip codes to maybe trim down each comparison in the subquery, for example `WHERE tableA.zip = tableB.zip`  but still not sure how to get that identifier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to find the nearest point is to aggregate sorting by distance, and take the first element, something like:

```
SELECT 
  table_a.idenfitier,
  ARRAY_AGG(table_b.identifier 
            ORDER BY ST_Distance(table_a.geog, table_b.geog) 
            LIMIT 1)
      [ORDINAL(1)] 
FROM ...
GROUP BY table_a.idenfitier
```

But as you correctly mentioned, cross product is very slow, so if you can - restrict the join to a limited radius using `ST_DWithin`.
Couple blog posts describe the ideas how to do this in BigQuery in details

https://mentin.medium.com/nearest-neighbor-in-bigquery-gis-7d50ebd5d63

https://mentin.medium.com/nearest-neighbor-using-bq-scripting-373241f5b2f5